# if else in loop bringing up errors in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function that is supposed to get referral codes from users. User gives a code and the referral code checked if it exists in the database then evaluated if

1. it does not match the current user, so that one should not refer himself and
2. it is a match with one of the codes in the database

This code however just does not find a match even if the code given is in the database. If the referral code matches the one of the current user, it works correctly and points that out i.e one cannot refer themselves.

But if the referral code is a match to that of another user which is how a referral system should work, it still says no match.

How can I remove this error

```
export const getID = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const usersSnapshot = await db.collection("user").get();
  const allUIDs = usersSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().userID);

  const userID = context.auth.uid;
  const providedID = "cNx7IuY6rZlR9mYSfb1hY7ROFY2";


 //db.collection("user").doc(providedID).collection("referrals").doc(userID);

  await check();

  function check() {
    let result;
    allUIDs.forEach(idFromDb => {
      if (providedID === idFromDb && (idFromDb === userID)) {
        result = "ownmatch";
      } else if (providedID === idFromDb && (idFromDb !== userID)) {
        result = "match";
      } else {
        result = "nomatch";
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  if (check() === "match") {
    return {
      message: `Match Found`,
    };
  } else if (check() === "ownmatch") {
    return {
      message: `Sorry, you can't use your own invite code`,
    };
  } else {
    return {
      message: `No User with that ID`
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're doing--are you expecting multiple results for the `forEach`? If so, you're overwriting `result` on each iteration so it'll be whatever condition was last `true`. If not, maybe don't `forEach`, because it's misleading. And I'm not sure why you keep calling `check` all over.

Comment: i need just one `result` from that `forEach` that is, if the `referralCode` matches but not to the current user or if the `referralCode` does not match. that is why i have put three checks for this

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: if you have multiple results from `allUIDs` you're going to get the last result, whether or not that's what you want. Seems like some simple debugging and/or console.logging would be enough to resolve this issue, whatever it is.

Comment: You should indent properly your code, it is painful and confusing to read it. You'll probably get an answer faster by presenting readable code.

Comment: I need to iterate through the documents fetched from the database. say 10 documents each with a unique id. if a user gives a code that matches with what is in the database, the 10 documents, it returns a match.

Comment: @Taio That's not what your code currently does.

Comment: It's also not clear to me what `db.collection("user").doc(providedID).collection("referrals").doc(userID)` is doing in there.

Comment: Yes that is not what it does. And I am wondering why. It finds the `own match` the `no match` but does not find a `match` even if the match is there

Comment: I have commented out that line, it was there by error

Comment: You can't return from a `forEach`. You have to declare a variable outside the loop, set it inside the loop, and return it after the loop. Make sure not to set the variable more than once within the loop; you may need to set a flag indicating the value has already been set. Or, just use a `for` or `for..of` loop.

Comment: I *told* you why: `result` will be set to the last comparison in your `forEach` loop. See the running commentary in my refactoring (which is *not* an answer, but looking at your code was a bit painful, so I had to fix it first) and decide what you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is not an answer, but a simple refactoring.)

This is what your code is currently doing (roughly, I didn't run it):

```
const resultMsgs = {
  nomatch:  'No User With That ID',
  ownmatch: 'Sorry, you can\'t use your own invite code',
  match:    'Match Found',
}

function check(uids, providedId, userId) {
  let result

  uids.forEach(idFromDb => {
    if (providedId !== idFromDb) {
      result = 'nomatch'
      return
    }

    if (userID === idFromDb) {
      result = 'ownmatch'
      return
    }

    result = 'match'
  })

  return result
}

export const getID = functions
  .https
  .onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const userId     = context.auth.uid
    const providedId = 'cNx7IuY6rZlR9mYSfb1hY7ROFY2'

    const db   = admin.firestore()
    const user = await db.collection('user').get()
    const uids = user.docs.map(doc => doc.data().userId)

    const checkResult = check(uids, providedId, userId)
    return { message: resultMsgs[checkResult] }
  })
```

(I removed the seemingly-spurious db collection operation.)

Your `forEach` is iterating over all of the `uuids`, but `result` will be set to whatever the last comparison was. Perhaps this is correct, but:

- If you're looking for *any* match, this is not what you want.
- If you're looking for *all* matches, this is not what you want.
- If you're looking to match the *last* UUID, it's what you want, but an odd way to go about it.

So:

- If you want *any* matches, use... *ahem* any form of an `any` function.
- If you want *all* matches, use any form of an `all` function.
- If you want the *first* match, then just check the first element.
- If you want the complete *set* of comparisons then you'll need to use `map` instead of `forEach`, and handle each result appropriately, whatever that means in your case.

In any event, I'd recommend breaking up your code more cleanly. It'll be much easier to reason about, and fix.